# PF rule, opening port 8080 on OpenBSD with IPv6

Tags: java, ipv6, openbsd

What I want to achieve is to access a website on my OpenBSD machine that has an IPv6 while I don't. For this I'm using Tunnel Broker and I can successfully ssh into the OpenBSD machine using its IPv6 address.

A web app is running on this machine on port 8080 and I'd like to access it from my machine (that uses Tunnel Broker). The OpenBSD machine is behind a modem/router but I've allowed all connections coming from the IPv6 given to me by Tunnel Broker.

Therefore, I'm guessing my issue has to do with the OpenBSD firewall... I've tried many different rules but none have worked. Here is the last one I tried:

```
pass in proto tcp from any to nfe0 port 8080
```

Each time I use `pfctl -nvf /etc/pf.conf` to reload the rules. To test the connection I do:

```
$ curl -6 http://[ipv6]:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ... port 8080: Connection refused
```

I can ping6 the machine without problem... Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

I use OpenBSD 6.0 and my machine is on macOS Sierra.

**EDIT**

I've create a very simple HTTP server in Java that tries to listen on [::1]:8080 but I get the following error:

```
$ java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleServer ::1 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at SimpleServer.main(SimpleServer.java:13)
```

(I get the same error when I try to bind Tomcat to ::1). My code:

```
public class SimpleHTTPServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080, 10, Inet6Address.getByName(args[0]))) {

            String line;
            String content = "Hello World!";
            String response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: " + content.length() + "\n\n" + content;

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeBytes(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

It looks like there's an issue with the JDK and IPv6 on OpenBSD, even when compiled with the with_ipv6 flavor... For the moment I'm using relayd(8) to pass all IPv6 packets to the internal IPv4 address to which my server is listening to.

**EDIT3**

Problem should have been fixed in the latest jdk port version.

Comment: You need to actually have something listening on port 8080. Right now you don't.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well yes I do, I have a Spring Boot application that listens to port 8080. Is that what you mean?

Comment: How do you know it's listening on port 8080? Have you checked?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I can for example do `curl 127.0.0.1:8080` (from the OpenBSD machine, using ssh) and the page is correctly returned...

Comment: Nonono, you didn't test IPv6 connectivity! It is not listening on IPv6. Which is what you've been asking about!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Indeed, `netstat -an` shows me it's only listening on IPv4... I've tried without success to make Tomcat listen to IPv6, maybe this is a problem with OpenBSD & Java... (The Java error I get is "protocol family unavailable")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.

http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/devel/jdk/1.8/pkg/README-main?rev=1.2&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup

> Eliminiate with_ipv6 FLAVOR. ipv6 will be included in the main package
>   by default now. However ipv4 will continue to be the default address
>   family in the package. To enable ipv6 (and disable ipv4 in the process),
>   see package README's.

README:

```
ipv4 to ipv6 address mapping is disabled on OpenBSD. This means the
jdk can only use ipv4 addresses or ipv6 addresses but not both at
the same time. By default ipv4 addresses are enabled. To use ipv6
addresses set the following properties when you start java:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```